# Glue chunks of files together in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, upload

I've written a File API uploader, which essentially does the following:

1. User selects files to upload
2. The files are sliced into 20 kb chunks
3. The chunks are sent asynchronous to a php script
4. PHP waits until all chunks are uploaded, and then glues all the temporary files together
5. The file - glued together - is saved

However, PHP doesn't glue them together very well. Sometimes, the file is glued together well, but most of the times (especially on files with a lot of chunks) the file's are glued together wrong.

The js code: (works only in Firefox 4 beta):

```
 sendChunk: function(file, start, length) {
    var raw  = file.raw;
    var name  = file.name;
    var total  = file.size;

    var url = 'upload.php?name=' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '&total=' + total + '&start=' + start + '&length=' + length;
    var slice = raw.slice(start, length);
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsBinaryString(slice);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        if(e.target.readyState === FileReader.DONE) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", url);
            xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined-binary');
            xhr.sendAsBinary(e.target.result);
        }
    };
};
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php
$filename = $_GET['name'];
$total = $_GET['total'];
$start = $_GET['start'];
$length = $_GET['length'];

$uploaded = $start + $length;
$percentage = round($uploaded / ($total / 100));
$remaining = $total - $uploaded;

$fd = fopen("php://input", "r");
while($data = fread( $fd, 10000000)) file_put_contents("./tmp/$filename.$start", $data, FILE_APPEND);

if($remaining <= 0) {
    $handle  = opendir('tmp/');
    $data   = '';
    $collection = array();

    while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
        $arr  = explode('.', $file);
        $name  = '';
        $start  = $arr[count($arr) - 1];

        for($i = 0; $i < (count($arr) - 1); $i++) {
            if($name == '') $name .= $arr[$i];
            else $name .= '.' . $arr[$i];
        }

        if($name == $filename) {
            $collection[$start] = file_get_contents('./tmp/' . $file);
        }

        @unlink('./tmp/' . $file);
    }

    ksort($collection);

    foreach($collection as $key => $bin) {
        echo "(Added) $key: (binary data)\n";
        $data .= $bin;
    }

    if($data !== '') {
        file_put_contents('./uploads/' . $filename, $data);
    }

    closedir($handle);
} else {
    echo "Uploaded: $uploaded / $total ($percentage%)\n";
    echo "Remaining: " . $remaining . " (". (100 - $percentage) ."%)\n";
}
?>
```

Anybody has any idea? My guess is that the FileReader works asynchronous, and it somehow sends the wrong chunk with the wrong `start` & `length` parameters in the `sendChunk` method.

Comment: you should to format your code for readability! ;-)

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use $_FILES and not read from stdin.

Comment: Well, that don't work since I don't send it as multipart/form-data

Comment: That is a very good idea (sending it in chunks). Perhaps you could queue the ajax requests so that you only send one at once? Also, are you checking that the data is indeed an image on the server side, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the way you are sending the data to the server, but I my first guess would be to change

```
$fd = fopen("php://input", "r");
```

to

```
$fd = fopen("php://input", "rb");
```

so the stream-reader is binary-safe.

**Edit:**

Since I am not familiar with the php://input stream and I don't know exaclty what data it includes and in what format, I recommend using POST data instead both in client and serverside.

So I would change JS like this:

```
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", url);
            xhr.overrideMimeType("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.send('data='+encodeURIComponent(e.target.result));
```

and the PHP like this:

```
file_put_contents("./tmp/$filename.$start", $_POST['data']);
```

Comment: well, it did something... look at the output now: http://fabdrol.com.s3.amazonaws.com/1415_IMG_8799.jpg

Comment: would it be possible to use a tool like `diff` to see where your data is being changed?

Comment: Added new ideas if you don't have the solution yet